# will RHEL process my ifcfg-ens192.bak.xxx file?

Tags: rhel, ip, ifconfig

Recently, we made a clone of a RHEL VM for testing purposes. One of the steps to make the clone unique was to give it a different IP address than the original machine (Of course). But the method used was to back up the current file to one called 'ifcfg-ens192.bak.xyz'. Then the ifcfg-ens192 was given the new IP.

While the clone was online, we encountered many strange things happening which may or may not have been caused by a duplicate IP on the network. The networking guys haven't chimed in yet as to whether a duplicate IP was found on the network.. but my question is, could the startup routines of the server somehow have read that file also, and used that information to set the incorrect, old IP?

Comment: I’m pretty sure it reads every file named ifcfg-* and uses the device name in it, which means that it’s reading the second file too.

Comment: Yes; I believe you're right. We found that indeed this was the case. Nobody has "Answered" this question; So I can't mark it as solved.